# How to force the system to use AMD gpu card as default gpu

Tags: graphics, radeon, amdgpu

This is my first question here, how do i force my laptop to always use amd gpu when starting applications?
i have a workaround with `xrandr --listproviders` and `xrandr --setprovideroffloadsink` , then `DRI_PRIME=1 [app name]`. but that doesnt fix things like applications that launched from another applications and wine emulated. so how do i force my laptop to use amd gpu as default?
Specs:
Lenovo G40-70
Graphics:
Hybrid of
Intel Haswell ULT Integrated Graphics
AMD Sun LE [Radeon HD R5 M230]

Comment: Use the AMD GPU as opposed to what?  Do you have another GPU?  Applications do not all work for GPUs; they have to programmed in a special way in order to make use of them.  If you have two in your system and you want an application to pick one over another, then that's something that maybe someone here can help you with.  But if you want a program to use the GPU as opposed to something that's not the GPU...then that's not something we can help you with.  That depends on how that program was made...

Comment: i have the workaround of DRI_PRIME=1 but that does not fix everything, just things that are launchable using terminal. things such as minecraft or something like that require amd gpu to be default or i'll be writing a lllloong line of code just to launch one, and i dont know how :(. i have intel integrated gpu and amd dedicated gpu if you wonder. how to... 'prioritize' amd over intel when rendering opengl, starting from the awakening of the session? (sorry for bad english, im indonesian)